# What is the difference between 'const auto& element' and 'auto element'?

Tags: c++, auto

```
template <typename T>
void DisplayVector(const vector<T>& inVec)
{
    for (const auto& element : inVec)
        cout << element << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
void DisplayVector(const vector<T>& inVec)
{
    for (auto element : inVec)
        cout << element << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

How much information (like `const` and `&`) can the compiler infer from the type of `inVec`? What is the ***type difference*** of the two `element`s in the above code?

Comment: The second copies each element. The first uses the value directly from the vector using a const reference

Comment: `auto const&` is a `const` reference (an *alias*) to the member in the vector *in situ*.  `auto&&` is a reference to the member in the vector *in situ*, which will be `const` if needed.  `auto` will be a *copy* of the member.  `auto&` will be a reference that will fail if it needs to be `const`.